# Hadoop shows a different number of map input records than lines in all files in a directory

Tags: linux, hadoop

I'm experimenting with `Hadoop 2.2.0` and I've created a simple unique line identifier program. Currently my program takes in a directory and I believe the maps should be passed lines from the files that I specify in the directory.

However when I do a `cat | wc -l` on my linux box, I see my count is 36063, but when my `MapReduce` job is running, I see this: `Map input records=64974`.

This is a single-node run, and I am using the local file system.

Here is my `Job` setup information:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

Here is my `Map` function:

```
public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, NullWritable> {
    private static final NullWritable nullWritable = NullWritable.get();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(value, nullWritable);
    }
}
```

What could be the cause of this count being off?

//EDIT: 
I believe this all may have been caused by some of these being binary files. If I use Text based files, everything counts correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the local file system or to HDFS?  the input/output paths are typically the latter.

Other debugging tips:

- Print out the paths inside your M/R driver program.
- for f in ; do hadoop dfs -cat $f | wc -l

Comment: Local filesystem, I added that in the question. I have verified that the number of files scanned through are the same.

Comment: OK, please verify the filesystem URI and the paths to each of the files in question as well as their sizes as the next troubleshooting step.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by this? I have verified that path to each file is corrects my Hadoop job prints out the file names when parsing. I haven't verified the sizes. How do you recommend I get file sizes in Hadoop?

Comment: Well the next thing I thought of was to ensure the files are the same. Actually better: do an md5 checksum on the contents.

Comment: Will do when I can. That's a great idea. A question: When Hadoop does a file split by line, what does it us as a delimiter? most of the files I'm doing are XML, so a line should be `\r\n`.

Comment: \n is the default line delimiter for TextInputFormat